# Div layout troubles

Tags: asp.net, css, layout

I have a search result page that I'm trying to layout but I'm having problems getting the results to be centered on the page. This is the current layout that I have:

[image]

The darker borders are for the outermost `divs` on the page. The Red border is how I would like the results to fill into and not drop down or reorganize if the page is resized.

Here is the html content designed using `ASP.NET`

```
<div class="Content_Container">
    <div class="SearchResultContentDiv">
        <div id="SearchBar" class="PatientSearchBarDiv">
            <div id="InnerSearchBarDiv" >
                <SB:SearchBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server"></SB:SearchBox>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="AdvancedSearchLink" runat="server">Advanced Search</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="SearchFilter" class="PFSDiv" >
            <SFC:SearchFilterControl ID="SearchFilterControl" runat="server"></SFC:SearchFilterControl>
        </div>
        <div id="SearchResultDiv" >
            <SRC:SearchResultControl ID="SearchResultControl" runat="server" /></SRC:SearchResultControl>
        </div>
        <div id="SearchResultClearDiv"></div>
   </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTraverseDisplay" runat="server" CssClass="SearchResultRecordsLabel" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is kind of a mess.

```
.SearchResultContentDiv {
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

The top bar has this layout:

```
.PatientSearchBarDiv {
    height: 50px;
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

The filter has this layout:

```
.PFSDiv {
    width: 130px;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px 5px 5px 3px;
    color: #2D666F;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

The main search result layout is:

```
.SearchResultDiv {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 135px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

And the bottom `div` box doesn't have a layout.

Like I said above, I want the search result in the center to fill up the empty area, but not move and/or rearrange itself. For example, I tried adding `width: 100%` to `.SearchResultDiv` but caused the search results to drop below the search filter.

I'm still learning HTML and CSS layouts, so I'm not sure what the best combination I should use. As always, any and all advice is greatly appreciated.

Oh, and I don't know if this is relevant, but the search result is generated using `ASP.NET`'s Repeater, and I've yet to figure out how to make that expand the remaining width of the page.

Finally, I've considered using `Tables` but I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) that's generally not a good idea.

**UPDATE**

After reading @CBRRacer comment about how `float:left` will cause the element to "shrink wrap" as he put it, I decided to remove that property.

In the code above, I have a Control labelled `SearchResultControl` with layout set as:

```
<asp:Panel ID="SearchResultPanel" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" style="background-color:White;margin-right:5px;">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        onitemcreated="Repeater1_ItemCreated" >        
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemTemplatePlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="background-color: White"><hr /></td>
        </tr>
        </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

The `float:left` was set for the `Panel` and that caused it to not fill up as I wanted it to. After removing that, I got the result I was looking for.

Comment: Post your HTML, styles and scripts into http://jsfiddle.net and I bet you will get more people willing to help you with this.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your SearchResultsControl user control html markup as well.  Also any time you float a div it will shrink wrap so that means you need to set the width on the results div to 100%.  Also I would style the filter off of the ID instead of a class unless you are using that class in two location on the same page.

Comment: Bah! It was a simple matter of floating. I looked into the floating thing @CBRRacer mentioned and removed it from `SearchResultDiv` but kept it in for the search filter and it's laying out the way I want it to.

Comment: @EK0nomik; I thought about doing that, but most of the content is generated from the server. The Search Results are generated with a `Repeater` so I wasn't sure how I'd best do that in jsfiddle. I was going to copy and paste the generated code in Chrome, but after looking at it, I decided against it. In the future, I'll try and do it that way, if it's easier to do. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `float:left` that was set in the `SearchResultControl`. See update.

Answer (score 0):

On `.SearchResultDiv`, you might try setting `width` slightly less than 100% (99% or 98%), or you could try setting its `margin-right` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="SearchResultDiv" style="width: 100%;" >
     <div style="width:auto; margin: 0 auto;">
        <SRC:SearchResultControl ID="SearchResultControl" runat="server" /></SRC:SearchResultControl>
     </div>
</div>
```